# selenium cannot have effect when clicking on a link with an onclick method

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium

The element is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="submitViaAjax(null, url);return false;">Add</a>
```

when I use element.click() to click the link, it does not execute the onclick method.

How can I make it executing the method?

Thanks!

Comment: if a person clicks on it and it is executed, it will also work for selenium.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably something wrong with the way you are accessing the element. Try this to find and click on the element.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#']")).click();